# Spark groupByKey using column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an algorithm in spark which I belive can only be efficiently implemented as a cogroup.  At the moment I’m achieving this with datasets by performing a groupByKey operation in the two datasets I need to merge.

The problem with this approach is that it’s less efficient than it could be on the map side as it means allocating Java objects for both the row object and and also the key. Ideally I’d use data frames on the map side and just use supply col columns to group by which should remove the need for this allocation, then switch to datasets for the cogroup.

My question, therefore, is whether it is possible to get cogroup functionality in spark while avoiding the extra allocation on the map side.

Comment: There is a cogroup function in RDD. Did you try that ? Sample usage http://apachesparkbook.blogspot.com/2015/12/cogroup-example.html

Comment: Hi @AvishekBhattacharya.  With the Rdd ths will suffer from the same problem as spark will need to allocate objects on the map side for the key and the record object.